# Power BI - Bulk import/export Measures

Tags: import, powerbi, export, measure

Is there any way to import/export measure expressions from excel file in POWER BI?

Its a pain to create all the measures again in every small project.

i know its possible in Qlik sense and other Business Intelligent tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, although not as straight forward as a simple click Export, click Import.

**Let me offer up a few options.**

1. Use [Excelerator BI's amazing spreadsheet](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/measure-dependencies-power-bi/) to extract and copy over measures.
2. Use [DAX Studio](https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/dax-studio/) to copy paste from one to the other (individually)
3. [Use a PowerBI shared dataset](https://radacad.com/power-bi-shared-datasets-what-is-it-how-does-it-work-and-why-should-you-care). Create your data model in a blank PowerBI. Publish it. Use the published dataset as a source for all your reports/PBIXs that need to depend on a shared model.
4. If they are simple, move the calculations out of your PowerBI in to upstream ETL processes or aggregations on your database.

Comment: Does any of the solutions allow a bulk copy of all the measures? Or are the proposed solutions just convenient ways of copying the measures one by one?

Comment: DAX Studio has a bulk export for measures.

Answer (score 0):

Three real options from worst to best. The worst option should always work, and the best option doesn't always work.

1. This YouTube shows how to bulk copy and paste by hacking the .pbit file.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TdSp-lCGNk

You can do similar now also from a .pbip file.

It's not a pretty process either way, and it is WAY messier for Report Level Measures (a measure that is defined in a Power BI report that is connected to a model in SSAS or the Power BI Service, often called a "thin report"). As far as I'm seeing, Report Level Measures are only defined in the report json, and it is heavily escaped and requires a lot of reformatting before you could do anything with them.

2. I think the best route for Report Level Measures is to use [Report Analyzer](https://github.com/m-kovalsky/ReportAnalyzer) to get a list of measures and then [ModelAutoBuild](https://github.com/m-kovalsky/ModelAutoBuild) to add them. ModelAutoBuild may be the easiest way for even normal measures, but I haven't done it yet.
3. The last approach is to use [ALM Toolkit](http://alm-toolkit.com/) to compare the 2 Power BI files and generate a script to copy the measures from one model to another. I've had issues with this lately, but often I'm trying to move measures between SSAS and Power BI and it doesn't always work.